# Will apple reject my app on autolayout warnings?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, warnings, nslayoutconstraint

I made iPhone app targeting iOS 6

My app runs very smoothly and there is no crash in the app during launch and anywhere in the app.. but my app shows some warnings related to `autolayout`.

I tried a lot to solve this warnings but i didn't success..

**Warnings in NSLog :**

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xac85e50 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0xac745f0.height == UINavigationTransitionView:0xab9b110.height - 64>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xac71d60 V:[UITableView:0xb161200(307)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xac73230 UITableView:0xb161200.bottom == UIView:0xac72b20.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xac731b0 V:|-(>=153)-[UITableView:0xb161200]   (Names: '|':UIView:0xac72b20 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xac84610 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0xac72b20.height == UIViewControllerWrapperView:0xac745f0.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xabcac10 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0xc085ad0.height == UIWindow:0xc06c990.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xabcca20 h=--- v=--- V:[UIWindow:0xc06c990(568)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xabc8dd0 h=-&- v=-&- UITransitionView:0xc086e40.height == UILayoutContainerView:0xc085ad0.height - 49>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xabc7660 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0xab9b5d0.height == UITransitionView:0xc086e40.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xabc42e0 h=-&- v=-&- UINavigationTransitionView:0xab9b110.height == UILayoutContainerView:0xab9b190.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xabc5a00 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0xab9b190.height == UIViewControllerWrapperView:0xab9b5d0.height>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xac71d60 V:[UITableView:0xb161200(307)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

because of this warning, will my app will be rejected if I submit it to the App Store?

Comment: why not try to fix the problem?

Comment: I tried a lot to solve this warnings but i didn't success.. :(

Comment: read this `Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xac71d60 V:[UITableView:0xb161200(307)]>` so figure out where does this constraint come from and maybe delete it

Comment: I do agree with @xlc0212. Admittedly, autolayout warnings can seem daunting, but the problem itself is often very trivial. If you wish to create and release a reliable application, then I recommend debugging this issue to try and solve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple does not consider warnings during the approval process. The dynamic check looks for undocumented methods, private APIs, etc.Then the content is also checked. I also have some warning due to third party libaries in my code and none of my apps have been rejected due to warnings.